# Let Σ= {a}, assume language, L= { a^(2012.K) / K> 0}, what is minimum number of states needed in a DFA to recognize L

Tags: finite-automata, computation-theory, dfa, nfa

In my opinion it should be 2012 but I am not sure.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: just for curiosity!!!

Comment: 2012 would be the correct answer for K>=0.

Comment: See the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) for a way to find the number of states a DFA would need.

Comment: Thanks for the reference by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

States are 2013..

from S0 to S2012.. S2012 is final state, S0 is starting..

transition from S0--->S1--->......S2012 ---> S1..